# intent.getCategories() is null although it was set

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm using this intent-filter configuration for an Activity to launch my app upon being called by a script embedded in a website:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="myapp" />
</intent-filter>
```

This works fine as my test device HTC One M8 with Android 6.0 launches the app as designed. I can access query-parameters of the URL with this code in the Activity's `onCreate` method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
  if (intent != null) {
    if (intent.getAction() != null) {
      if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
        if (intent.getCategories() != null) {
          if (intent.getCategories().contains(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)) {
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            uri.getQueryParameter("id")
            // launch another activity with this information
          }}}}} // flattened for this question
```

Unfortunately, one test device is a Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 6.0. I can't get through to query-parameters because the log states `intent.getCategories()` is `null`. How can this work with an HTC but not with a Samsung device?

My assumption is that the Galaxy S6 might have more RAM than the HTC and thus possibly stores the activity longer (?) which result is that the Intent is still the initial intent to run the app before the `schema` intent-filter started the Activity. Any ideas how I can ensure that the `schema` intent is used as soon as the app received it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [Category test](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#CategoryTest) states

> For an intent to pass the category test, every category in the Intent must match a category in the filter.

That also implies, that an intent might pass this test, when there's no category in the intent itself. So you should not rely on these categories being present, thus returning `null`. Also different devices have different browsers pre-installed. And these might create the intents differently. The Samsung one might not consider your script link browsable.

Instead you should only rely on the action and the data

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null && Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    if (data != null && "myapp".equals(data.getScheme())) {
        data.getQueryParameter("id")
        // launch another activity with this information
    }
}
```

Or maybe even only on the data if you want.

Comment: Your code worked and I'm grateful for your help. Thank you for the explanation.